# How to prevent state passed as props from giving undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Good day ,I'm quite new to reactjs and I'm trying to pass state as props but it keeps giving me undefined in the component I want to make use of it in. This is where I pass the state, workspacelist is the component receiving the state

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import Background8 from '../Images/house3.jpg';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Workspacelist from '../Workspace/Workspacelist';



function BoardList({ boards }) {
    const history = useHistory()
    const [currentid, setcurrentid] = useState("")
    const navigate = (id) => {
        setcurrentid(id)
        history.push('./workspace');
        return <Workspacelist id = {currentid} />
    }
    return (
        <>
            {
                boards.map((board) => (
                    <li key={board.id} className="boardlist" style={styles} onClick={() => navigate(board.id)}>
                        <h3>{board.title}</h3>
                    </li>
                ))}
        </>
    )
}
export default BoardList
```

This is the short version of workspacelist component where I receive it

```
import React from 'react'

function Workspacelist({ id }) {

    console.log(id)
}
```

but any time I log id it returns undefined

Comment: checked ur code. worked for me. check your boards data again.

Comment: `console.log(boards)` to see that the data exists.